# How to find string and return it to stdout in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I am getting familiar with Python & am struggling to do the below with BeautifulSoup, Python.

What is expected:

*If the output of the script below contains the string `5378`, it should email me with the line the string appears.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import urllib2,re

import codecs
import sys
streamWriter = codecs.lookup('utf-8')[-1]
sys.stdout = streamWriter(sys.stdout)

BASE_URL = "http://outlet.us.dell.com/ARBOnlineSales/Online/InventorySearch.aspx?c=us&cs=22&l=en&s=dfh&brandid=2201&fid=111162"

webpage = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.read(), "lxml")
findcolumn = soup.find("div", {"id": "itemheader-FN"})
name = findcolumn.text.strip()
print name
```

I tried using `findall(5378, name)`, but it returns to empty braces like this `[]`.

- I am struggling with Unicode issues if I am trying to use it along with `grep`.

`$ python dell.py | grep 5378
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dell.py", line 18, in <module>
    print name
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 817: ordinal not in range(128)`

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong in both cases?

Comment: What operating system and version?

Comment: when you use piping `|` then `print` doesn't know what encoding it has to use so you have to encode on your own - ie. `print name.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: check in doc - i'm not sure but i think `findall` expects tag name as first argument . `5378` is not tag name.

Comment: @chrki It's Mac Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `findall` (from the `re` module) expects the first parameter to be a a regular expression, which is a string, but you provided an integer. Try this instead:

```
re.findall("5378", name)
```

When printed this will output `[u'5378']` when it found something or `[]` when it didn't.

I suspect you want to retrieve the product name from the number, which means you have to iterate through elements in `findcolumn`. We can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) here to check for a single match within the element's texts.

```
for input_element in findcolumn.find_all("div"):
    name = unicode(input_element.text.strip())
    if re.search("5378", name) != None:
        print unicode(name)
```

As for the unicode error, there are a bunch of solutions, depending on your operating system and configuration: [Reconfigure your system locale on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393638/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x-in-position-ordinal-n) or [Encode your script output with `.encode()`/`unicode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20).

Comment: Ty. I set the encoding at the OS level. It works! When I run it, it shows `[u'5378']` but I want the entire line to be printed instead of just `[u'5378']`. How can I do this?

Comment: It works, thank you! Why do you have to redo a `findcolumn.find_all("div"):` and not just `findcolumn` as we are already doing it in `findcolumn = soup.find("div", {"id": "itemheader-FN"})`? So, I tried `for input_element in findcolumn:` and am getting this error and am getting this error `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`. Can you please explain?

Comment: @deppfx In `findcolumn` there are more child element `div`s, each of those contains one laptop product name, I'm using `find_all` to get these into an array. Otherwise you are just searching the single whole `findcolumn` element (a div containing more divs, inputs, etc.), it's not an array and that's why you get that error because it is treated as a Beautifulsoup `NavigableString` in that case (not iterable, i.e. can't be looped over with a `for .. in`)

Comment: I would double upvote you if I could. Thanks for explaining it in detail. :-) I am going to read and learn about what `NavigableString` in beautifulsoup is about. And why I can't do a `soup.find_all` in line 14 itself (it didn't work).